# Change/Update same content on multiple pages using element ID (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

;)

I have a website (wordpress) with multiple pages with specific prices for each country (but there are fixed fees for all of them). All the prices changes every year (including fixed) so I need to update each one, one by one, page by page.. So, here's my question, is there anyway to update similar content on all pages at the same time? Each price are simple text shortcode, so I can setup an ID element for each one. For example:

- Price 1: 5  ->ID Element: price1
- Price 2: 5  ->ID Element: price2

If I change "5" by "10" on price 1.. is there anyway to upload price 2 at the same time?? In other words, when I change the content of "price1" ID element, I need the "price2" ID element changes too, is it possible??

Any suggestions will be awesome ;)

Thanks!

Comment: It probably is, but SO won't code it for you :P

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I'm not 100% clear on which price goes where, and how they're calculated. Can you add price examples and which prices appear on which pages?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions ;).

I don't need to recalculate any price because I will need to replace them manually, all I want is save time to not replace equal content on every page (and do it just once). Maybe I can "link".. some ID elements.. in order to be updated at the same time..when I change the content of one of them ? I have no idea if that's possible :s

Comment: We haven't made any suggestions yet :) I'm asking you to clarify the structure of those prices. A shortcode will run PHP code, which in turn has access to all kinds of information about the current page, so this is easily possible. But I don't know which price you want to end up where. Are there multiple prices per page? Multiple countries per page? If you change price 1, and want to update price 2 automatically, are we talking about two prices appearing on the same page, but for different countries? Take a step back and describe the bigger picture. The actual thing you want to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like this is about selling products, and shipping. How is your website structured? Is it one page per product? Etc. This is what I need to know. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks all for your replys! ;) I finally found a plugin which could work! It's "bruckets", if anyone need same solution ;). With it, I can replace same content on other pages of my website with just one edition.